# use columns of table in sub query level 2

Tags: mysql

I have query with have 2 level subqueries and i want to use column of table in the level 2 subquery, How I can make it?

it always give me error column of table not found

```
SELECT * FROM `stores` 
   WHERE
   (SELECT COUNT(ss.id) FROM 
    (SELECT order_stores.id FROM orders AS order_stores  
             WHERE stores.id = order_stores.store_id 
                AND order_stores.id < 0) AS ss) != 0;
```

it give me this error Unknown column 'stores.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: You also going to get  `Unknown column 'oo.id'`

Comment: May I know this `AND order_stores.id < 0` , you're looking for id which is smaller than '0'?

Answer (score 0):

Let's dissect this.
If we translate your whole query, it would mean "I want to find in `stores` where the total `COUNT(ss.id)` from my table `orders` where the `order_stores.store_id` is bigger than `0`".

Your core query is this:

```
SELECT oo.id FROM orders AS order_stores  
             WHERE stores.id = order_stores.store_id 
                AND oo.id < 0;
```

First of all, you didn't define where the `oo` table here. Secondly, you're trying to match a column from way outside the sub-query itself. This won't work.

You can try with a single query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(ss.id) 
  FROM stores ss 
  JOIN orders os  
    ON ss.id = os.id 
 WHERE os.id > 0 
HAVING COUNT(ss.id) !=0;
```

If you want to see how many count for each stores.id, you can try the following query:

```
SELECT ss.id,COUNT(ss.id) 
   FROM stores ss 
   JOIN orders os  
     ON ss.id = os.id 
  WHERE os.id > 0 
GROUP BY ss.id
HAVING COUNT(ss.id) !=0;
```

Note: I have change the `WHERE os.id < 0` (id is smaller than '0') to `WHERE os.id > 0` (id is bigger than '0') assuming that it's what you're looking for. But if it's the other way around, you can just change the `>` symbol.